# Highcharts downloading a graph with a pattern as an svg

Tags: javascript, svg, plugins, highcharts

I am trying to generate a highcharts graph with a pattern using the http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill plugin.

Though it works perfectly, i am unable to download an svg with a pattern in the graph. The documentation for the plugin says the svg is not implemented in this version. How can I go about it? Any other plugins which have this option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. I used the highcharts offline exporting module with the pattern fill plugin and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Well if this is a one-time only operation, I am using print to PDF from the web browser and then [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) to open the PDF and extract whatever I want. You could try this approach. Otherwise feel free to extend the plugin and add SVG support yourself. SVG is a text format therefore it shouldn't be hard to extract the info and apply the patterns...

Comment: No. It is not a one-time operation. Can you please elaborate on how to add SVG support myself? Any references?